# Ordering newly created numerical variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I created an interaction term based on two numerical variables. I would like the smaller number to always appear first (except for 0, which I would like to always appear last) in the interaction values.

Here is the code I used to generate the new variable, but I cannot figure out how to condition the smaller number to appear first (regardless of which variable, inter1 or inter2, it comes from).

```
Recent$interaction <- cbind(paste(Recent$inter1, Recent$inter2))
```

I also successfully created the interaction using this code:

```
Recent$interaction <- as.numeric(paste(Recent$inter1, Recent$inter2, sep = "")
```

Thank you!

Sample data:

| inter1 | inter2 |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |

Comment: Can you please provide sample data for Recent$inter1 and Recent$inter 2? I think arrange() might do the trick but want to make sure with the sample data first.

Comment: Hello Papuha, thank you so much for responding. I apologize, but how can I provide you sample data? Should I just type it out in this comment?

Comment: You can try this command
sample_data <- data.frame(inter1 = c(1,2,3), inter2 = c(2,3,4))

Comment: Thank you so much. I've included it in the original post now. But it doesn't seem to format right. I apologize you are having to walk me through this simple task

Answer (score 0):

I think the tricky part of your question is you want 0 to be last. So, we cannot just simply use a column as numeric as an arrange function will always put 0 first.

The solution is to make the sorted column a factor variable. So let's start by creating a sample data.

```
data1 <- data.frame(inter1 = c(5,2,3,0,5,6))
data2 <- data.frame(inter2 = c(2,3,4,5,6,0))
```

Next, I'll combine them.

```
combine <- cbind(data1, data2)
```

If you only want to sort this code would just work.

```
combine %>%
  arrange(
    inter1
  )
```

But since you want 0 to be last but still sort by number. We need to change a sorting variable which I assume in this case is inter 1 a factor variable.

```
combine$inter1 <- factor(
  combine$inter1,
  levels = c(2,3,4,5,6,0)
)
```

Then we try again

```
combine %>%
  arrange(
    inter1
  )
```

You should get what you want. The issue with this approach is that if you have value from 0 to 999999. Then the levels approach will be too tedious to input order manually. But I based the solution from the data you provide which is only a few numbers.

Let me know if you have too many unique values to manually put in levels, then we can work on another method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case_when` to specify different conditions.

```
with(df, dplyr::case_when(inter1 == 0 ~ paste0(inter2, inter1), 
                          inter2 == 0 ~ paste0(inter1, inter2), 
                          TRUE ~ paste0(pmin(inter1, inter2), 
                                        pmax(inter1, inter2))))

#[1] "35" "27" "57" "57" "37" "15" "20"
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(inter1 = c(5, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 2), inter2 = c(3L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```